# No pages showing for categories in magento

Tags: php, magento, categories, magento-1.8

I want to call a page in magento based on what category I choose in my custom navigation menu. But whenever I load my bar, it does not show any href link to my category. This is what I did for the menu:

```
<?php $_helper1 = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
    <?php $_categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
                     ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                     ->addAttributeToSelect('is_active'); ?>
            <div class="sidebar" style="display:block;">
                <h3>Product Categories</h3>
                <ul>
            <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
        <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $_category->getCategoryUrl($_category); ?>">
            <span><?php echo $_category->getName(); ?></span>
        </a>
        </li>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
```

and the output always shows:

```
<a href="">
            <span>Category 1</span>
        </a>
```

I also do not know how to set what products should only show in every category. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to show some text block in categories. This is default function of Magento.

1. Create CMS block (CMS -> Static Block), may be name it `My Category1 Block`.
2. Edit your Category1 (Catalog -> Manage Categories).
3. Click on Display Setting Tab.
4. Choose Display mode you like. In your case it would be `Static Block and products`
5. In CMS Block, select `My Category1 Block`.

To assign product to a category, you have to edit product and look category tab, from there you can associate product to a category.

Comment: do I need to add something in my static block to show the grid? I normally put this code, {{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}} , or do I leave it blank?